# User Form und MultiPage

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multipage

I Have a UserForm anwith a Multipage (2 Sides) I have also a worksheet called DATA. The User Form as weell as the ListBox has labels and textboxes. Some Textboxes goteNames (for ex. Me.Name). Also the Labels for ex Label 87 got the Name "Number". I also have a cmd Buttons (espec.2 buttons) One finds Datas in the Sheet DATA the other changes the CHnages made in a Textbox as well in Listbx as in Data sheet. See Code. But this code does not work. Whats my fault?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim i As Integer
 
  With tbl_DATA
    'Überschrift der Userform aus Zelle A1 holen
    Me.Caption = .Range("A1").Value
  
    For i = 1 To 10
      Me.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = .Cells(2, i).Value
    Next i
  
    'Überschrift der ListBox aus Tabelle holen
    For i = 1 To 8
      Me.Controls("Label" & i + 10).Caption = .Cells(2, i).Value
    Next i
  End With
 
  'ListBox einstellen
  With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 10                    'Spaltenanzahl festlegen
    .ColumnWidths = "80;80;80;80;80;80;80;80;80;10" 'Spaltenbreiten definieren
  End With
 
  'Cursor standardmäßig in die erste TextBox setzen
  Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an English speaking site.

Comment: I Have a UserForm anwith a Multipage (2 Sides) I have also a worksheet called DATA. The User Form as weell as the ListBox has labels and textboxes. Some Textboxes goteNames (for ex. Me.Name). Also the Labels for ex Label 87 got the Name Number.

Comment: I Have a UserForm anwith a Multipage (2 Sides) I have also a worksheet called DATA. The User Form as weell as the ListBox has labels and textboxes. Some Textboxes goteNames (for ex. Me.Name). Also the Labels for ex Label 87 got the Name "Number". I also have a cmd Buttons (espec.2 buttons) One  finds Datas in the Sheet DATA the other changes the CHnages made in a Textbox as well in Listbx as in Data sheet. See Code. But this code does not work. Whats my fault?

Comment: The post has an edit link underneath it to change your post, use that.  You are not using common terms.  It's not clear what "multipage (2 sides)" means.  What control are you referring to?  Or are you talking about a second form?  Same thing with "worksheet".  That term really only gets used when talking about Excel Spreadsheets.  What does "worksheet" mean?

Comment: Dear Lars.. Thx for your information. Sorry for inconveniance. I have an User Form . In this UserForm I have createt a Multiside. Controls.. I think that this is my fault cause I have named my textboxes (for ex. Texbox 1 is named "Prename". Workshhet is indeed an Excel Spreadsheet in a Workbook